# Writing a file to a specific directory

Tags: java, file-writing

I've created a simple program that would write a file with a directory using the following codes:

```
 String nameProve = nameField.getText();

 String employee = ("C:\\Users\\ALLEN\\workspace32bit\\RETRIEVE_CHECKER1\\RETRIEVE_CHECKED1" + nameProve + ".txt");

 PrintWriter outputStream1 = null;
 try
 {
    outputStream1 = new PrintWriter(employeeName);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can not write to " + employeeName);
    System.exit(0);
 }

 outputStream1.println("Employee Retrieve Executed");
 outputStream1.close();
```

I've already exported my code to a .jar file and my code works just fine if i execute it in the computer were I've develop my program but when I copied the jar file to other computer and I also created the forlder (manually) that corresponds with the directory in my codes my program doesn't work and my catch block will show the message   Can not write to "C:\Users\ALLEN\workspace32bit\RETRIEVE_CHECKER1\RETRIEVE_CHECKED1" + nameProve + ".txt"

Can anybody give me some advice on how to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the exception you are receiving?

Comment: Can not write to C:\Users\ALLEN\workspace32bit\RETRIEVE_CHECKER1\RETRIEVE_CHECKED1Edward.txt"  and after I click Ok the program exits and write method did not execute.

Comment: There should be a slash after `RETRIEVE_CHECKED1` and before `Edward.txt` otherwise it won't find the location.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are the user `ALLEN` on your machine and run the program as that user, so everithing works fine, because you are the owner of the directory `C:\Users\ALLEN`.

Then you copy the jar to another machine, where the user `ALLEN` does not exist and you are logged in as antoher user let's say his name is `Bob` and create that directory unter `C:\Users`. You may have noticed that you when you wanted to create that directory as the user `Bob` windows has warned you that you need admin priviledges in order to compleate this action.

Now you try to run your program with the user `Bob` who has access only to his own directory `C:\Users\Bob` and try to write to `ALLEN`'s own directory. So what happens is that you get an `IOException` telling you `access denied` which is good so!

You should not attepmt to write to other users private direcotries, this is a security issue.

In your code when dealing with filesystem, never hard code absolute path, always use relative paths, or if you need to defined a direcotry where all the data needed yb you program should be located, then pass ist as argument.

The simplest to do, ist use the following and work with the current [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

```
String employee = "RETRIEVE_CHECKER1\\RETRIEVE_CHECKED1" + nameProve + ".txt";
```

You need to create the directory `RETRIEVE_CHECKER1` either by hand in location where you run the program, or better yet in your program using [File#mkdir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir--) and use it like this:

```
File employee = new File(dir, "RETRIEVE_CHECKED1" + nameProve + ".txt");
PrintWriter outputStream1 = new PrintWriter(employeeName);
```

Comment: thanks man...... not to familiar with computer name and security issues. this helps a lot.

Comment: I did try a reading method with the same directory path, I manually    copied the .txt file to another station when i run my program which  was already exported to a jar file it works it reads the file and I'm using the same file directory, any explanation why my reading method works and not my writing method?

Comment: @user3796035 Users on a computer are granted access rights on diferent resources, most common rights are `read`, `write`, and `execute`, first two are obvious, third is for running an executable file. If you look at the properties of the file you are able to read or the directory you are able to read from in the security tab you'll find the users who can access it, by selecting a user, you'll see which rights are granted to him. You can find more on this topic [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions).

Comment: @user3796035 In `java` you can check for thoss permissions uisinf the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class and its methods [canRead()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead--), [canWrite()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite--) and [canExecute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canExecute--). PS: feel free to upvote and/or accept any helpfull answer!

Answer (score 0):

Exception you catch will have all details- like access denied, directory not exist, etc. Currently you loose exception data (message, stacktrace) when catching it.

Please do something like

- Do not catch just *java.lang.Exception*. This is too wide- will catch possible *NullPointerException* and present misleading message '"Can not write to'. Catch only specific exception instead- ones that are actually thrown from try block. In your case, that will be *java.io.FileNotFoundException*
- Do not loose exception details. Print it to the standard error log, or even better use loging framework

catch block that adresses  those issues:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```